# Having trouble accessing keys in a map in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am converting a string to map, and print the keys and values and it all looks good. I print the keys using keySet() and their values using values() and all show up as expected.
However, when I try to access any of the keys using get() or checking using containsKey() it fails and returns false.
Here are the print statements and results:

```
println("====== the keys and values: " + dlmap.keySet() + "   " + dlmap.values())
Which prints:
====== the keys and values: [ "URL", "DOWNLOAD_FILE", "PROCESS_FILE"] ["www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads", "sdn_xml.zip", "sdn.xml"]
```

but, the none of the keys can be accessed. Here is an example:

```
println("====== contains key URL: " + dlmap.containsKey("URL"))
which prints:  
====== contains key URL: false
```

I checked the original input string that is converted to map and there are no hidden characters.

Any help or clue is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: I don't think I can reproduce it. Can you put the whole of your code and run in GroovyConsole? and please share your code here. I think the key question here is how you create the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `.toString()` can often be misleading.  The reason, why you see
`"URL"` is because your keys actually contain `"` around the key.  If in
doubt, prefer `.inspect()` over a simple `.toString()` for debugging to
find problems like this easier.

```
def map = ['"URL"': "https://example.com", "URL": "https://example.com"]
println map.keySet()
// ⇒ ["URL", URL]
println map.keySet().inspect()
// ⇒ ['"URL"', 'URL']
```

Comment: Good catch!!.. That's the most likely explanation.

Comment: @ChayneP.S. unless OP "tweaked" the print result - and the space between `[ "URL"` would be a good indicator for that

Comment: @cfrick Thank you so much or your quick and correct response. Appreciate it!